# Is there a way to make the controls on QGIS android larger?

Tags: qgis, android

Is there a way to make the controls on QGIS android larger? e.g. When typing text into a field in the table view it is currently very small.

I also have a issue/bug where the panels (layers, gps controls) go very small (smaller than usual) and toggling them on and off, restarting QGIS android doesn't make them come back to their usual size.